# Generated code is not compiled

Tags: maven, maven-3

I wrote a `Mojo` that creates a new Java class and puts it in `/target/generated-sources/annotations`. in addition, I have configured `build-helper-maven-plugin` to declare that folder as source folder.

The problem is when I do: `mvn clean install` from CLI it generates the source file but it doesn't compile it.

Note, if I run `Maven Install` from within Eclipse (using the m2e connector) then it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: First what kind of code generation? Using the build-helper-maven-plugin is the wrong way cause if you wrote a plugin your plugin should handle this...

Comment: I'm using JavaPoet for generating a class and saving it into the target folder. What do you mean by "your plugin should handle this..." ? 

Comment: Cause you wrote `..I wrote a Mojo..` this means your plugin should handle that correctly...which it obviously does not...You need to add parts in your plugin...There is a thing `getProject().addCompileSourceRoot???` something...I can't remember correctly...

Comment: yeah, solved by adding instance of MavenProject which allows the suggested functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual plugin definition, we can only speculate.

I can't comment on m2e, I see one obvious difference that you state by yourself: **mvn clean install** vs **mvn install**, but from the "bare" maven's standpoint,

here is one possible reason:

Maven has a concept of **phases** that comprise the lifecycle. An information about phases of default lifecycle is available [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Plugins (more precisely the "goals" of plugins) are something that usually gets attached to a particular phase.

Maven compiler plugin is attached to the compile phase, for example.

So, maybe the plugin that you've developed runs **later** than the compiler plugin.
Usually, source generation plugins are attached to **generate-resources** phase.

Its possible to run a full lifecycle in maven, in fact its what people usually do, for example, running **mvn test** actually means, run all phases of the default lifecycle up-to (including) phase **test**.

It's also possible however to run a particular plugin goal "directly" without attaching it to the phase. Of course, in this case, its pre-conditions should be met.

For example, **mvn surefire:test** means that we should invoke the surefire plugin directly. Of course the source code and test code should be compiled beforehand (bytecode has to exist in the *target* directory)

So I suggest you to run the following series of commands (Adjust if you have tests):

1. Run **mvn clean install** *on the plugin project* to place it to local m2 repo
2. Run the plugin directly: **mvn :::** and check 
   whether the source is generated in the target folder
3. Make sure in pom.xml of the project that the source folder are configured correctly
4. Run **mvn compile** (phase up-to, including, compile) on pom even without the plugin
   After this phase, there will be compiled sources in the *target* directory. Don't run 
   **clean** because it will wipe out all the target directory

This will effectively help to make sure that plugin does the job right